# Angular and rerun script

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, themes

I have a theme who needs to re-execute the scripts.js (to do the style of the page).

I already tried to put all .js files on angular.json (but doenst work).

So, I looked at Lyfecycle hook, and at a component who i ask theme.component.ts i put the imports at ngAfterViewInit and my theme worked like a charm.

```
import('../../../assets/js/utils/app.js');
import('../../../assets/js/utils/page-loader.js');
```

When i navigate to the next page my theme doenst work anymore for the next component(inside theme.component.ts).

Thinking on that, i created a subscription on my route

```
this.mySubscription = this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).pipe(map(() => this.activatedRoute)).subscribe((event) => {
    import('../../../assets/js/utils/app.js');
    import('../../../assets/js/utils/page-loader.js');
     })
```

But this doenst work too, because the scripts do not run again (maybe cache?), but the subscribe works very well.

I am looking for a solution to rerun my theme scripts on every navigation.

I appreciate some suggestion.

Comment: This looks pretty weird.. importing doesn’t mean execution and I really don’t understand the need to keep re-importing in the first place. Your app is a single page application so once imported (globally at least) - the scripts are there. So what do these scripts do actually and how are they triggered?

Comment: They do the visual of the page, like pageloader and avatars.
The script looks for the DOM searching .class do make the magic like a canvas or svg, but do it once... so when i navigate he doenst trigger again.

Comment: No possibility to just have Angular take care of all that?

Comment: now its a lot of work i guess. to remake all the theme.